# extracting substring from string

Tags: perl, substring, extract

I am a perl noob still. I am getting a string which can be man_1, man_2, woman1, woman2 etc.. (no commas and there will be only one string as input to the function).

I need to check man_ or woman as substring in if statements to make sure appropriate number is extracted and some offset is added.

the number i can extract as below

```
$num =~ s/\D//g
if (<need the substring extracted> == "man_")
    $offset = 100;
else if (<need the substring extracted> == "woman")
    $offset = 10;

return $num + $offset;
```

Now how do I extract the substring. I looked at substr and it requires offsets and what not. Couldnt figure out. Appreciate the help

Comment: the numbers can go all the way to 1024 for the string being passed to the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
if ( $num =~ m{^man_(\d+)$} ) {
    return 100 + $1;
} elsif ( $num =~ m{^woman(\d+)$} ) {
    return 10 + $1;
} else {
    die "Bad input: $num\n";
}
```

In your example there is couple of problems:

1. s/\D//g - will remove the characters, but one-by-one, and not as big block of all \D characters. So there is no variable that would be "man_"
2. to get data from regexp, you should use grouping parens, like s/(\D)//
3. to get all characters, you should use * or + operators, like: s/(\D+)//
4. Its still better to match without modifying, as it gives you better handling of edge cases of malformed data.

Answer (score 0):

depesz has a good solution. Here's another:

```
my %offsets = (
   'man_'  => 100,
   'woman' =>  10,
);

my ($prefix, $num) = $str =~ /^(\D+)(\d+)\z/
   or die;
my $offset = $offsets{$prefix}
   or die;
return $num + $offset;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
return $2 + ( $1 eq 'man_' ? 100 : 10 )
  if $num =~ /^(man_|woman)(\d+)\z/;

die;
```